# Multiple chrome instances with one user (remote VM)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I want multiple people to remotely log in on a VM with the same user and use 'individual' Chrome instances. (they don't have access to chrome on their devices)

So far I've tried multiple solutions:

- Windows Server -> needed licenses for more than 2 sessions
- Linux Server -> multiple sessions with 1 users works but can't run multiple sessions of Chrome simultaneously

Is there a way to run multiple Chrome sessions simultaneously on Linux ?
Or is there a better way to do this?